# Oracle invalid character list

Tags: oracle11g, invalid-characters

I have a problem with a database where I suspect that there are some invalid characters. As far as I know, there could be invalid characters that are not able to insert in a registry, but I can't find which ones are.

Could any of you tell me which characters are invalid to insert in a database? I'm working with Oracle 11g, but can't tell which encoding I'm using.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem do you have, and why do you suspect there are invalid characters? What do you mean by invalid - not part of your database character set? You can get the database and national character sets from `nls_database_parameters`.

Comment: Well, I have a script that works in some environments, but fails in one of them. The databases are exactly the same, but the one where doesn't work has other kind of information inserted in it for that reason I suspect that could fail because of that. There are characters that doesn't appear in the databases where the script works.